# Correct way to handle make an external URL call in Scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Scala and Play 2.0 so this may be a very straightforward question.  I have the following code (pseucoded for brevity):

```
var someExternalUrl = ...
def oauth = Action { request =>
    val paramMap = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v.mkString }
    if (paramMap.contains("error")) {
      // Redirect to error page
    } else {
      val d2 = Duration(1000, "millis")
      val futureResponse = ws.url(someExternalUrl).withQueryString(...).toString).get()

      var m = futureResponse.map(response => {
        val json = response.json

        val userId: String = (json \ "user_id").as[String]
        Redirect(routes.Application.home()).withSession(
        "user_id" -> userId
        )
      })
      Await.result(m, d2)
    }
```

}

is this the correct way to process the result of the call to the external URl?  I've seen posts that speak of using onComplete to handle futures instead of using Await because it is blocking.

Comment: Use `Action.async` instead of `Action` and remove `Await.result`

Comment: How do I do I show the error page?  I have something like this: `Ok(views.html.error..)` and it gives me syntax error when I use `Action.async`

Comment: `Future(Ok(views.html.error..))` use this. as the return type of your action is now `Future[Result]`

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @curious, Play provides `Action.async` for such cases. More info on the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync#Returning-futures

Doing an `Await` is (almost?) never a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You are using Action and because of that you have to use Await.result for any method call that returns Future[T].
Whenever you are using a method that returns Future[T], consider using Action.async because it allows you to return Future[Result].
Action.async is available since play 2.2 or 2.3.

Following is your code with Action.async

```
def oauth = Action { request =>
  val paramMap = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v.mkString }
  if (paramMap.contains("error")) {
    // Redirect to error page
  } else {
    val d2 = Duration(1000, "millis")
    val futureResponse = ws.url(someExternalUrl).withQueryString(...).toString).get()

    futureResponse.map(response => {
      val json = response.json
      val userId: String = (json \ "user_id").as[String]
      Redirect(routes.Application.home()).withSession(
        "user_id" -> userId
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Play 2.0 is too old, you should update it to at least 2.4, if possible go for 2.5.